# Почему не устанавливается vue-cli?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

Доброго времени суток.
При глобальной установке vue-cli возникает ошибка
windows 10 , node обновлен

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
at Object. ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:470:27)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:613:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# устанавливаем vue-cli
$ npm install --global vue-cli
```

> вот если что записал видео [установка vue-cli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-lD7eTPC-o&t=112s)